# Very slow compilation when biolinum, tcolorbox's listings library, and multiple listings' dialects involved

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, compiling, biolinum

The compilation of the following MCE is *very* slow: about 14 second on my “normal” computer. (Of course, my real use case does load different dialects, not the same one several times.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{biolinum}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{mytcblisting}{%
  listing options={%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, the compilation is less slow:

- if `biolinum` is not loaded (about 8 seconds),
- if the dialect is, unlike the `LaTeX` one, *not* based on a base dialect (`LaTeX` is a `TeX` dialect based on the `TeX`'s base dialect `common`, as it can be seen in `lstlang3.sty`, line 1454). This is shown by the following MCE:

  - as is, the compilation time is about 11 seconds,
  - if `\lstdefinelanguage[foo]{TeX}[LaTeX]{TeX}` is replaced by `\lstdefinelanguage[foo]{TeX}`, the compilation time is about 4 seconds,
  - if, in addition, `biolinum` is not loaded, the compilation time is about 2 seconds.

What's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{biolinum}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage[foo]{TeX}[LaTeX]{TeX}%
{%
  morekeywords={%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
  },%
  morekeywords=[2]{%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
  },%
  morekeywords=[3]{%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
  },%
  morekeywords=[4]{%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
    foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,%
  },%
  sensitive,%
}[keywords,tex,comments]%

\newtcblisting{mytcblisting}{%
    listing options={
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
      alsolanguage={[foo]TeX},%
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}

\begin{mytcblisting}
Foo
\end{mytcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the bottleneck is when the auxiliary file `.listing` is written out. A ***VERY LONG*** list of keywords is examined each time.